# Is there any method in netty ssl client to know if server requested client certificate after completion of SSL Handshake process

Tags: ssl, netty

I have a **Netty HTTPS(SSL ENABLED) Client** which communicates with both Mutual Authentication **enabled** servers and Mutual Authentication **non-enabled servers**.

Following is the code I use to Setup SSL Handler for Client.

```
TrustManagerFactory tmf= ...// Necessary Trust certs
KeyManagerFactory kmf = ...// Necessary Client certs
SslContext sslContext = SslContextBuilder.forClient().keyManager(kmf).trustManager(tmf).build();
SslHandler sslHandler = sslContex.newHandler(ByteBuffAllocator);
```

I use the above `sslHandler` in the pipeline. I know that providing `keyManager(kmf)` will provide client certificate to server if server requests. Everything works as expected.

**MY NEED** : I need to know if the Server requested Client certificate or not(ie. Mutual Auth enabled server or not) in SSL Handshake process. I need to know this after completion of Handshake process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could provide your own `KeyManager` implementation (that later calls the actual KeyManager). If [getPrivateKey()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/X509KeyManager.html#getPrivateKey(java.lang.String)) is called you know that the server has requested the client certificate.